# tweepy retweet a tweet as fast as a user tweet one

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

making a twitter bot whit python 2.7 and tweepy api, want to make so my bot will retweet a tweet as fast as a user tweet one. Like @IRetweetTrump do it. I was trying to code some code whit tweepy api but doesn't work. 
here is my code

Edit1: the code retweet user, but how do i so it will run always and retweet the latest tweet.

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=25073877).items():
    try:
        # Add \n escape character to print() to organize tweets
        print('\nTweet by: @' + tweet.user.screen_name)

        # Retweet tweets as they are found
        tweet.retweet()
        print('Retweeted the tweet')


         #Favorite the tweet
         #tweet.favorite()
         #print('Favorited the tweet')


        time.sleep(3600)  # take a sleep for in sec

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)  # if cant Retweet tweets, print the reason

    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: what exactly does not work?

Comment: have not found a way to retweet a tweet as fast as a user tweet one.

Comment: probably because of [rate limits](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting). Try using streaming API; [tweepy offers one](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.4.0/streaming_how_to.html).

Comment: will take a look

Comment: @hoefling check edit, need more help